# error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] in Android Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Hello I am trying to inject a reporitory to a viewModel in android and is failing with the following issue:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] error.NonExistentClass cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements ApplicationName_GeneratedInjector
```

This is my viewModel

```
   @HiltViewModel
   class AuthenticationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: WellthiRepository,
   ): ViewModel() {
   }
```

And this is my repository

```
class WellthiRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val tokenManager: TokenManager,
    private val tokenService: TokenService,
    private val userManager: UserManager
){}
```

If I remove the inject part from my viewModel then it works completely fine, but I need that repository injected to my viewModel.

Comment: where do you have @Provide method for `WellthiRepository` ?

Comment: No, I don't have. How and where should I add it?

Comment: You have to create a [module](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-hilt#6) and provide the dependency with proper scope there r multiple scopes already available with Hilt check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android). follow the code lab .